# What are well known examples for models?

Tags: transformation, modeling

I'm currently writing a blog entry that is also about model-2-model transformations. I would like to explain shortly what a model-2-model transformation is in this post. Therefore I would like to come up with a simple example of two models, where the first is transformed to an instance of the second. Both models should be well known to developers, so that I don't need to explain them.

However I couldn't come up with some example models. [ATL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/) uses a family and person model in [one of their tutorials](http://wiki.eclipse.org/ATL/Tutorials_-_Create_a_simple_ATL_transformation), but they also require extra explanation as I think.

So do you know an example that I can make use of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to explain m2m to developers, you can use an M2M-trafo from petri nets to uml activity diagrams. Because activity diagrams are based on petri nets it should not be to complex. I think both models should be known by a developer. Sure, they are not easy, but a developer should know them.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram

Sure you should keep as simple as possible. This means you should only describe the transformation for a subset of modeling possibilities. For petri nets I only would use simple states and transitions as subset of the metamodel. For activity diagrams I only would use actions and transitions.

There should already be existing examples of this transformation, so you can also use existing knowledge.

Another thing I want to point out is, that someone how learns M2M-trafo understands what M2M-trafos are used for. Because this case described above can be used in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I chose object relational mapping (ORM) as an example in my blog post. ORM can be viewed as a bidirectional transformation from a relational database model to an object oriented in memory model.

Most (every) developer should know about ORM. But the problem might be that this could cause devs to think about m2m in terms of Hibernate, JPA, etc, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

As an example you may consider translation from one language to another. There is an example of translation from [UML to OWL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/usecases/ODMImplementation/).